# Linux on Arm Cortex- M1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I am new on embedded programming. Now I am a bit confused about ARM Cortex M1 series.
I need to know, can I run Linux on ARM Cortex-M1 based fpga system.
When I search the web I couldn't find any toolchain or buildroot for development.

Can anyone enlighten me that Cortex M1 has Linux support? If not would you offer any other cpu core for Linux with low power consumption?

Comment: if there is a strong need for an operating system most folks use an RTOS like freertos or one of the many others.  Not fully linux capable as answered below, not worth the effort to try  to get a non-mmu linux running, if you even have the resources for that.

Comment: Cortex-M1 is nearly identical to Cortex-M0. It does not have an MMU, which makes Linux hard. For Linux, usually people use Cortex-A. There is an A5 DesignStart, but only for Asic. Or find an FPGA with a hard core (runs much faster).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend not to use Linux on Cortex-M1. It's a microcontroller, not a microprocessor. You cannot run mainline Linux since lack of MMU. Furthermore, since Cortex-M1 is a FPGA-based microcontroller, would you implement all peripherals and port to Linux??

There is a variant of the Linux kernel for processors without MMU called uCLinux, but it will be somewhat limited.

Try using Xilinx Zynq FPGA, which has Cortex-A as a CPU.

Comment: FPGA model is Microsemi including. Which soft cpu core am I supposed to use in order to get Linux support? I would consider Linux previously because I have a legacy code which is written for Linux.

Comment: @roll Why do you need a soft CPU core in order to run your legacy code? Just get an any ARM board.